# How to Control Firefix Dialog box with Autoit?

Tags: autoit

i try to click on OK button on firefix dialog box.

My code:

```
Local $hWnd=WinActivate("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]")
WinWaitActive($hWnd)
;MsgBox(1,$hWnd,$hWnd)
ControlClick($hWnd,"Ouverture de codeblocks_13-12_fr_430815.exe","Enregistrer le fichier")
;ControlClick($hWnd,"&Save File","")
;Close("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]")
```

When i launch, it happens nothing, the dialog box is still there but the file is not downloaded.

Comment: Any chance you could give the URL for us?

Comment: URL = http://www.clubic.com/telecharger-fiche430815-code-blocks.html

Comment: Is the click command trying to click on the first orange button in the window?

Comment: no the click command does not trying to click any button

Comment: I thought you are trying to click the orange box to start the download, then click the next box to save the file. Am I mistaken? You have the save file `ControlClick` and `Close` commented out, meaning they won't do anything..

Comment: No i try to click directly the "Save" button, after clicking manually the orange button

Comment: The dialog box is already open i just want to click on "Save" button

Comment: i uncommented but nothing has changed, the file is still not downloaded, did u try it the code

Comment: Give my answer a try with the save box open, I'm very certain this should work for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work with the function `MouseClick` after giving the window 2 seconds (`sleep(2000)`) to bring up the save file button.

```
Local $hWnd=WinActivate("[CLASS:MozillaDialogClass]"), $sWnd, $try, $coords
WinWaitActive($hWnd)
$sWnd = WinActivate("Opening code-blocks_13-12_fr_430815.exe")
WinWaitActive($sWnd)
$coords = WinGetPos($sWnd)
sleep(2000)
$try = MouseClick("", $coords[0] + 297, $coords[1] + 170, 1, 1)
If $try = 0 Then
    MsgBox(0, "error", "Did not work")
EndIf
```

Comment: How did you execute this code, for me i execute the code sciTE and then i click on Tools/Go

Comment: With your modified code, it just close the window with downloading the file

Comment: with or while? because that is exactly what you asked for. A way to click on the save file button and start the download. that is what I have done here, and I've also tested it so I know it works :)

Comment: It s very strangem i saw it cliking on Save button and then close the dialog box but the file is not downloaded in my download folder.

Comment: take out the `WinClose()`

Comment: now it works, i don't know how, Thank you Mr. Hargrove

Comment: No problem, glad it works (even if it seems magic) @user3745193 :)

Comment: Thank you Mr.Hargrove, i caanot use Autoit, it works sometimes for example when i try, it does not work well. I need to find another solution, if you anyidea how i can do, please provide informations, thank you for your help

Comment: Using the FF.au3 library you can do exactly this, as someone has already made the functions for you. Just give it a search and you should find it under example scripts in the autoit forum.

Comment: @user3745193 here is the library - http://www.thorsten-willert.de/Themen/FFau3/FF.au3/FF.au3?a